# If query fails with AND but works with OR

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, json

I search a JSON tree with jQuery on keyup-event. If the input is equal to the desired entry the input will disabled.

Now I need to call a function if they all are filled and correct. The if queries are long so i have written them into variables.

I've tried this, but it **fails**:

```
if (simple_present && simple_past && past_participle) {
    alert('All right!');
}
```

Now, when I write something like this, it **works**:

```
if (simple_present || simple_past || past_participle) {
    alert('All right!');
}
```

Here's a fiddle of [what I have so far](http://jsfiddle.net/ARTsinn/NnAMu/0).

Any ideas?

BTW: What is the best way to combine long if queries with reg expressions​?

Comment: If only you knew how to debug JavaScript via the browser's dev tools... `:P` (You have to put a break point on the `if` statement and inspect the values of the variables that are in the if-header. Since "it fails", (at least) one of the variables will obviously be falsy.)

Comment: @Šime Vidas: I know what you mean but to implement that is my knowledge about javascript to poor ;) Some code will help, maybe?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this:

```
var json = {
    "vocables": {
        "irregular": {
            "sein": {
                "simple_present": "be",
                "simple_past": "was were",
                "past_participle": "been"
            },
            "schlagen": {
                "simple_present": "beat",
                "simple_past": "beat",
                "past_participle": "beaten"
            },
            "werden": {
                "simple_present": "become",
                "simple_past": "became",
                "past_participle": "become"
            }
        }
    }
};

var word = $( 'h1' ).text();

$( 'input' ).on( 'keyup', function () {
    if ( this.value === json.vocables.irregular[ word ][ this.id ] ) {
        $( this ).prop( 'disabled', true ).next( 'input' ).focus();
    }

    if ( $( 'input:not(:disabled)' ).length === 0 ) {
        alert( 'SUCCESS' );
    }
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/NnAMu/1/

As you can see, I have:

- changed the JSON structure to suit my needs better,
- cached the current word into a variable.

With those changes, the resulting "keyup" handler code is much simpler.

Comment: Wow! Much better... Thanks alot!

Comment: @yckart: Your third item (`werden`) does not have a simple past, by the way.

Comment: @pimvdb: Yeah I know the json tree is not really completed yet ;)

Answer (score 2):

You run all of the following code in the same event handler for each element:

```
$this.attr('id') == 'simple_present'
$this.attr('id') == 'simple_past'
$this.attr('id') == 'past_participle'
```

They can't be all true, so `&&` is guaranteed to give you `false`.

Comment: Btw, note for OP: `this.id` works fine. No need to use jQuery here.

Comment: @yckart: Probably you will want to only validate the current input field and have variables (or an object) that keeps track of the correctness of each text field. You can then validate each input independently.

Answer (score 0):

Add a debug line just before the if:

```
alert( simple_present.toString() + '\n' + simple_past.toString() + '\n' + past_participle.toString() );
```